# Langchain: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'

Tags: python, import, module, python-import, langchain

When I write code in VS Code, beginning with:

```
import os
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
```

I am met with the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'`

I have updated my Python to version 3.11.4, have updated pip, and reinstalled langchain. I have also checked sys.path and the folder `C:\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages` in which the Langchain folder is, is appended.

EDIT: Langchain import works when I run it in the Python console (functionality works too), but when I run the code from the VSCode run button it still provides the ModuleNotFoundError.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had installed packages with `python 3.9.7` but this version was causing issues so I switched to `Python 3.10`. When I installed the `langhcain` it was in `python 3.9.7` directory. If yo run `pip show langchain`, you get this

```
Name: langchain
Version: 0.0.220
Summary: Building applications with LLMs through composability
Home-page: https://www.github.com/hwchase17/langchain
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: /home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, async-timeout, dataclasses-json, langchainplus-sdk, numexpr, numpy, openapi-schema-pydantic, pydantic, PyYAML, requests, SQLAlchemy, tenacity
Required-by: jupyter_ai, jupyter_ai_magics
```

If you look at the `Location` property, you see this `/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages`. But since I am using `Pyhton3.10` I had to make sure `langchain` is in the directory of `Python 3.10`. so installed the `langhchain` with

```
python3.10 -m pip install langchain
```

now when I run, `python3.10 -m pip show langchain` I get this

```
Name: langchain
Version: 0.0.264
Summary: Building applications with LLMs through composability
Home-page: https://www.github.com/hwchase17/langchain
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: /home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, async-timeout, dataclasses-json, langsmith, numexpr, numpy, openapi-schema-pydantic, pydantic, PyYAML, requests, SQLAlchemy, tenacity
Required-by:
```

Now new `Location` is referring to `Python3.10` directory

Answer (score 0):

you probably didn't put your python file location into the enviroment variables.

copy your python file location
go to search>edit enviroment enviroment variables>user variables>path>new
put the copied python location in the user variables.
then try again!

Comment: if you edit the environment variables, remember to restart the computer

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention - I did also check this! But I found my solution, which I've also posted here.

Answer (score 0):

when installing in your environment try using:
`python -m pip install langchain`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I'm fairly sure this error was caused by pip installing files in the incorrect directory. Make sure the target directory is where your sys.path folder is, as sometimes these can vary! Thanks to everyone who provided advice.

Comment: You're on track using a venv. But you have to make sure the venv you created is _activated_ so when you install libraries they are installing into that specific virtual environment. Then, when you go to import in your script, make sure wherever you're running the code (VSCode, terminal, etc.), that you are using the python instance associated with the virtual env as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code in VS and you have more than one Python version, please check if the bottom right side of the VS Window the version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by creating a virtual environment first and then installing `langchain`.

Open an empty folder in VSCode then in terminal:

1. Create a new virtual environment `python -m venv myvirtenv` where `myvirtenv` is the name of your virtual environment.
2. In terminal type `myvirtenv/Scripts/activate` to activate your virtual environment. (If this does not work then type `cd .\myvirtenv\Scripts` and hit enter, type `./activate` hit enter and then type `cd ../..` ) . Now your virtual environment should be activated in VScode.
3. Type `pip install langchain` and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install langchain
```

Install the Langchain libary.

You can install it by using pip and go in your terminal and type in the code

Answer (score 0):

- First, you can run this code in your terminal: `pip show langchain`. If the langchain is not present on your library, just run `pip install langchain`. You should also check version python, the requirement python version is `≥ 3.8. 1 and <4.0.` Quick installation [Installation Langchain](https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/installation)

I usually run langchian with python 3.11, my steps are as follows:

1. `conda create --name my_env python=3.11`
2. `conda activate my_env`
3. `pip install langchain`
4. `pip show langchain`