# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'

Tags: python, pdf, langchain, pdf-scraping

i tried to extract data from an unstructured pdf file in python Vscode, i searched all solutions in google without any improvement,

i struggled with an error when i tried to import LangChain library, although the installation was done successfully, even i tried to change the python kernel version to 3.8 , 3.9 , 3.10 , and finally 3.11. also i tried to change the langchain version from the last one 0.1.7 to 0.130 and 0.150 but the same issue i found it, with notice that i created venv , please i need help ,((i installed all packages with pip and its done successfully))

```
pip install langchain
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\requests-2.31.0')
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\langchain_core-0.1.24')
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\langchain-0.1.7')
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\langchain_community-0.0.21')
sys.path.append('C:\Program Files\aiohttp-3.9.3')
from langchain.document_loaders.image import UnstructuredImageLoader
```

---

```
--
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 from langchain.document_loaders.image import UnstructuredImageLoader

File C:\Program Files\langchain-0.1.7\langchain\document_loaders\__init__.py:22
     18 from typing import Any
     20 from langchain_core._api import LangChainDeprecationWarning
---> 22 from langchain.utils.interactive_env import is_interactive_env
     24 # For backwards compatibility
     25 _old_to_new_name = {
     26     "PagedPDFSplitter": "PyPDFLoader",
     27     "TelegramChatLoader": "TelegramChatFileLoader",
     28 }

File C:\Program Files\langchain-0.1.7\langchain\utils\__init__.py:7
      1 """
      2 **Utility functions** for LangChain.
      3 
      4 These functions do not depend on any other LangChain module.
      5 """
----> 7 from langchain_core.utils.formatting import StrictFormatter, formatter
      8 from langchain_core.utils.input import (
      9     get_bolded_text,
     10     get_color_mapping,
...
     14     "LANGCHAIN_HUB_URL_BASE",
     15     "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hwchase17/langchain-hub/{ref}/",
     16 )

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Comment: Probably pip points to some python installation you are not using. Try invoking pip canonically "python3 -m pip install langchain" (or whatever will point to the python installation you want) and then see.

Comment: @AxelSparrow can you please see my edited question, the installation was going alright, but i struggled with importing

Comment: In your venv, please run `pip list | grep langchain` to verify whether `langchain` has been installed

Comment: @j3ffyang this error shown up 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: i change the vscode into pycharm , now the error was :
Unused import statement 'from langchain.document_loaders.image import UnstructuredImageLoader'

Comment: Just realized that the env is on Windows. So you can run `pip freeze` instead, to list whether `langchain` and dependencies have been installed.

Comment: yes i found it  langchain==0.1.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Langchain: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726419/langchain-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-langchain)